# RVM ruby installation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I've got an ruby error I can't manage to fix. To be short ruby isn't working as it should. When I try to reinstall it with

```
rvm reinstall all --force
```

I get errors in the terminal, saying I should take a look at the .log files. Here is the content of the .log file:

```
[2013-07-26 18:51:22] __rvm_with
Restoring gems to pristine condition...
bigdecimal-1.2.0 ERROR:  Loading command: pristine (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
io-console-0.4.2 ERROR:  Loading command: pristine (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
json-1.7.7 ERROR:  Loading command: pristine (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
minitest-4.3.2 ERROR:  Loading command: pristine (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
psych-2.0.0 ERROR:  Loading command: pristine (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
rake-0.9.6 ERROR:  Loading command: pristine (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
rdoc-4.0.0 ERROR:  Loading command: pristine (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
test-unit-2.0.0.0 ERROR:  Loading command: pristine (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

'gem pristine bigdecimal --version 1.2.0 io-console --version 0.4.2 json --version 1.7.7 minitest --version 4.3.2 psych --version 2.0.0 rake --version 0.9.6 rdoc --version 4.0.0 test-unit --version 2.0.0.0' failed, you need to fix this gems manually.
```

I think the error appeared after installing the new xcode preview version but I'm not sure it has anything to do with that.

I'm on a mac using 10.8.4 mountain lion.

Does someone know how to fix this? Thank you!

Update:

After re-installing ssl and entering the rvm reinstall command, there is an error again in the  log file:

```
[2013-07-26 19:21:48] /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1073 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1082 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.2.0/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
/Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/security.rb:355: warning: already initialized constant Gem::Security::DIGEST_ALGORITHM
/Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/security.rb:355: warning: previous definition of DIGEST_ALGORITHM was here
/Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/security.rb:360: warning: already initialized constant Gem::Security::DIGEST_NAME
/Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/security.rb:360: warning: previous definition of DIGEST_NAME was here
/Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/security.rb:365: warning: already initialized constant Gem::Security::KEY_ALGORITHM
/Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/security.rb:365: warning: previous definition of KEY_ALGORITHM was here
/Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/security.rb:370: warning: already initialized constant Gem::Security::KEY_LENGTH
/Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/security.rb:370: warning: previous definition of KEY_LENGTH was here
/Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/security.rb:375: warning: already initialized constant Gem::Security::ONE_YEAR
/Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/security.rb:375: warning: previous definition of ONE_YEAR was here
/Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/security.rb:385: warning: already initialized constant Gem::Security::EXTENSIONS
/Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/security.rb:385: warning: previous definition of EXTENSIONS was here
/Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/security/policy.rb:23:in `initialize'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/security/policies.rb:6:in `new'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/security/policies.rb:6:in `<module:Security>'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/security/policies.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/security.rb:583:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/package.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/installer.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/request_set.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems.rb:200:in `finish_resolve'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/rdoc.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/uninstaller.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/commands/setup_command.rb:474:in `uninstall_old_gemcutter'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/commands/setup_command.rb:146:in `execute'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/command.rb:305:in `invoke_with_build_args'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/command_manager.rb:170:in `process_args'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/command_manager.rb:130:in `run'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.6/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:60:in `run'
    from setup.rb:45:in `<main>'
RubyGems 2.0.6 installed
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure "cannot load such file -- openssl" is a big hint as to what's wrong here. You probably need to install that. Posting questions like this without being specific about your platform (distribution, OS version, etc.) is asking people to guess about how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I added the system. I already entered the command for ssl installation. Weird it isn't installed. And thanks for the person who voted me down, maybe I should search for his questions to topics which were new to him and vote him down as well. (Which I will not do, but it is just unnecessary!)

Comment: People will down-vote your questions if they do not think they are helpful, or if you haven't demonstrated much in the way of effort to try and solve the problem before asking your question. *"What have you tried?"* is something you should answer in the course of asking your question. Remember, the vote is on the question, not you personally. Don't go and rage and vote-bomb people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run these commands in sequence in terminal, and close all and open new terminal

```
rvm get stable
rvm autolibs enable
rvm reinstall all --force
```